# I think I need to use 'one' instead of 'you' on this

Tags: grammar

I am creating an email signature and want to say 'You would have many more bucks if you quit passing them'. I am wanting to say it generally but not to use 'we' as I don't want to include myself.
I was thinking 'One would have many more bucks if (they or he/she does not seem to fit) quit passing them".
Is 'they' correct? Is there a more elegant way to express this?
thanks,
ds

Comment: How about "one would have many more bucks if one quits passing them"?

Comment: My opinion, either don't include a saying, or at least don't include that one.